# Sending FCM notification to Android from Laravel 5 and download file on click of notification Laravel code

Tags: php, android, laravel, push-notification

I want to send notification to an Android device. For that I use [this code](https://packagist.org/packages/brozot/laravel-fcm) (also available on [github](https://github.com/brozot/Laravel-FCM)). Now I want to send an image in that notification (note: this is done by `setIcon`) but I want set action for that image for download.

Please help me.

Comment: which platform code do you need exactly ?

Comment: i want it in laravel. but now i done it by setclickaction() of fcm notification file.. Thank you sir

Comment: no sir :) if you have solved then it would be good if you add your own answer of how you solved it so that future readers can get help.

Comment: https://github.com/brozot/Laravel-FCM I use this Facade add on to send notification but the drawback is that i cant send notifications to multiple apps (Server Keys) using this but that usually is  my unique and rare scenario

Comment: you can make array of multiple token like , $collection =collect([ 
 ['fcm_token'=>'1 device token']
 ,['fcm_token'=>'1 device token'],
 
 ]);
$tokens = $collection->pluck('fcm_token')->toArray();


$downstreamResponse = FCM::sendTo($tokens, $option, $notification); hope it help you.